# docker non-running in docker ps -a

Tags: docker

as far as I understood `#(nop)` are non running commands like `WORKDIR`, `ENV` and other, we can see those with `docker history` like

```
docker history centos:7
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
5e35e350aded        6 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           6 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.label-schema.sc…   0B
<missing>           6 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:45a381049c52b5664…   203MB
```

Question is, why am I seeing this:

```
docker ps -a 
...
0e2ae8f89a30        38e031c000c8                                                        "/bin/sh -c '#(nop) …"   15 months ago       Created                                                                            peaceful_shaw
```

Inspecting it I see that its `WORKDIR /automations` directive, tho question is how did it end up as a container? I have tried forcing a build to fail and see if those pop up but I don't see them in `docker ps -a`. I am not sure how these ended up here in a first place. Can anybody provide a clue or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

`docker history` command *Show the history of an image*. Basically it shows how an image was built and that's what you are seeing when you run and it's expected.

```
docker history centos:7
```

- `docker ps` command *List containers*
- `docker ps -a` command *Show all containers even exited(default shows just running)*

and when you run that command, you are actually seeing the containers.

If you want more understanding, please go through the below docker documentation.

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/
>
> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

Comment: I feel like you havent read the question, or question is not properly asked, if you scroll right docker ps output provided you shall see that command is non-operation command, `/bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /automations` in my case, i obviously havent ran that container, neither can I reproduce that behavior by making my build fail,